# normalization in a DB

Tags: database, normalization

I wanted to normalize my table to all 3NF I believe that all of the following is in 3NF because there is no transitivity. Please clarify this if I am wrong

CUSTOMERS (custID, custName, custAddress, custDOB, custEmail)
EMPLOYEES (empID, empName, empPhone, empAddress, BranchName)

The assumptions are each one employee works at multiple branches and each branch has one or more employees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The assumptions are each one employee works at multiple branches and each branch has one or more employees

But that is not what you have modeled.  In your relation, there is a functional dependence on branches and employees.

To understand that, lets think about how you would represent an employee that works at multiple branches in your relation.  The only way to do it is for there to be multiple rows with the same employee information, with only the BranchName field varying.  What about an employee that doesn't work at a branch at all (like the CEO),  well then there are no rows for that employee and he disappears completely!

Lets break that apart.

```
BRANCHES(branchID, BranchName)
EMPLOYEES(empID, empName, empPhone, empAddress)
```

But now we need to have a many to many correspondence between the two.  The preferred way to do that is with a join table.

```
BRANCHES_EMPLOYEES(branchID, empID)
```

Answer (score 3):

"but is the above already in 3NF?"

Your question is unanswerable.

For it to be formally answerable, you must provide:

- a **FULL** schema of your database (i.e. one that also models/represents the many-to-many relationship between employees and branches), and
- the **complete** set of identified attribute dependencies.

You gave only part of the former, and nothing of the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could have a single Person table with a Role table that showed which ones were customers and which were employees.  That design would allow someone to be both a customer AND an employee.  No repeating of names, better normalization.  Person is many-to-many with Role (a Person can have many Roles; a Role can belong to many Persons).

Comment: @EquinoX: I seriously doubt it. But we can only guess because you haven't specified any keys or dependencies.